# Unsure of issue with PHP login

Tags: php, mysql, html

This is the login system i've been working on. It seems no matter what I do it's sending me straight to the error page even if the login is valid.

1. I'm grabbing the username/password strings from the form.
2. The query is correct I tested it, then i'm binding in those variables.
3. Then it sends me to error page. How can I check if i'm retrieving a row correctly?

---

```
  <?php 
    function clean($str)
    {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    }

    //Sanitize the POST values

    $username = clean($_POST['username']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);

    /* Create a new mysqli object with database connection parameters */
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'draftdb');

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
        exit();
    }

    /* Is your username the same as the login_id? If not you need to change this query's where to use the username column not the login_id. */

    /* Create a prepared statement */
    if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("
        SELECT Login_ID, Login_PW
        FROM login  
        WHERE Login_ID=? AND Login_PW=?
    "))
    {
        /* Bind parameters
             s - string, b - boolean, i - int, etc */
        $stmt -> bind_param("ss", $username, md5($password));

        /* Execute it */
        $result = $stmt -> execute();

        //Check whether the query was successful or not
        if ($result === false) 
        {
            die("Query failed");
        }


        /* Bind results to variables that will be used within the fetch() loop. */
        $stmt -> bind_result($username, $password);

          /* Check the number of rows returned. */
        if ($stmt->num_rows !== 1) {
            //Login failed

            header("location: login-failed.php");
            exit();
        }

        /* Iterate over the results of the query. */
        while ($stmt->fetch())  
        { 
            //Login Successful
            if($stmt->num_rows > 0) 
            {
            session_regenerate_id();
            /* We can use $login_id, $firstname and $lastname cause we binded the result to those variables above. */
            $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $username;

            session_write_close();
            header("location: member-index.php");
            exit();
            }
         }//main if close



          /* Close statement */
          $stmt -> close();
       }

       /* Close connection */
       $mysqli -> close();
    ?>
```

### **Update concluded im not getting anything passed to my php script from my form**

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="login.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="username" type="text" id="username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="password" type="text" id="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_* functions. It's highly discouraged. (Line 8)

Comment: @Nile - the OP isn't. They're using mysqli.

Comment: @j08691 **line 8.** Unless that's supported in mysqli? Though I'm pretty sure it's `mysqli_real_escape_string`. That could be the problem also: using mysql_ when it should be mysqli_

Comment: @Nile - True however it's just the one line that's fixed by adding an "i". It's not like the OP is using all old mysql_ functions.

Comment: @j08691, thinking about it, it could be the problem... couldn't it? that may be why the user isnt getting desired results. **Edit:** also, hes using mysql_ (or a typo'd mysqli_) functions without creating a connection.

Comment: You are comparing $username with the LOGIN_ID data entry of your table.  Just from their names, it seems like one is text and the other is an integer.  Check that you're comparing the correct data.

Comment: @Vulcan they are both strings.

Comment: @Nile I'm creating a connection, and I changed the mysqli_real_escape_string still same error.

Comment: What error do you get? You just say "error page"

Comment: The problem is it's not passing in the values from the form, i've added the form i'm using can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` at the beginning of your script and post the result here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your form tags `<form name="form1" method="POST" action="login.php">` & `</form>` outside your table -

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="login.php">
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="username" type="text" id="username"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="password" type="text" id="password"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

A form is not allowed to be a child element of a `table`, `tbody` or `tr`. It need to either reside outside the `table` or fully inside `<td> <form ...> </form> </td>`